# WPF How To Tell If A Control Was Tabbed Into Focus?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I've got a ComboBox where I need to determine if it was tabbed into focus vs. clicked/touched into focus.

The ComboBox default behavior for being tabbed into focus does not open the drop-down part, which is different than if it is clicked/touched into focus...yet all three bring it into focus.

Comment: Would it work to have two event listeners: one GotFocus listener, and one Click listener? If this approach does not properly address your problem, could you give more information about what exactly you're trying to achieve?

Comment: You're on the right track. I need the drop-down to open when user tabs to the ComboBox and also when clicks/touches it.

Of course this happens with click/touch. And if I hook into either the GotFocus() or GotKeyboardFocus() events, these also get fired with click/touch. Then the result is weird behavior - the drop-down partly opens, flickers and then closes.

I've tried...

if(!myComboBox.IsDropDownOpen) { myComboBox.IsDropDownOpen = true; }

...within the GotFocus() and GotKeyboardFocus() event handlers, but it still doesn't work.

I need way to distinguish when ComboBox is tabbed into focus

Comment: I have tried to open the ComboBox to open the dropdown on GotFocus, And it is working fine. May be you would have some other junky code. Try with a simple sample. And check what is the difference b/w sample and your project. You can track the spot